# Regex that match with a entire word including Accented caracters

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to make a regex which searches some words that are invalid in my app.

I have this regex and works good:

```
/( |\\.|\\,|\\:|\\;|^)(one|two|three|four)( |\\.|\\,|\\:|\\;|$|s|\n)/gi
```

This will match good;

> This text will match with **one** regex

But this will not:

> This text will match with oné regex

How can I build a regex with javascript which includes that exception. That's for an app in spanish.

Answer (score 1):

Regex operates with ascii, therefore special characters are not recognized. You need to explicitly include those into your regex.

```
/( |\\.|\\,|\\:|\\;|^)(on[eé]|two|three|four)( |\\.|\\,|\\:|\\;|$|s|\n)/gi
```

A better solution would be to remove all accents from the document before running the regex.